# Does writeJSON method of fs-extra module maintain the order of Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, fs-extra

I am new to nodejs, I have an object of enumerable objects which has data like below:

```
const obj = {
    "id3" : {
       "userName":"name3",
       "age":"age3"
    },
    "id2" : {
       "userName":"name2",
       "age":"age2"
    },
    "id1" : {
       "userName":"name1",
       "age":"age1"
    },
    ...
}
```

when I want to dump this object to a file using writeJSON method of fs-extra, Is the order maintained? i.e., when I am reading it by readJSON method will I get the object in the same order?

Comment: If you care about order you should be using an array.

Comment: Eventhough, `Object.keys` returns a specific order of keys, strictly speaking there is no "order" in an Object, and you shouldn't rely on any specific order while iterating an object.

Comment: I don't want to use array because I want to get the data by id frequently. What would be the better way to do this? Is it better to use Map(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: If you get your data by key anyways, why would the order within the object be of any relevance?

Comment: If the key is not provided, I should return the first inserted entry - that's the use case.